# CSS navigational bar: text following UL is floating around - why?

Tags: css

I was playing around with the horizontal navigational bar of this site:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5

With following code:

```
<head>
<style>
ul
{
     float:left;
     width:100%;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     list-style-type:none;
}
a
{
     float:left;
     width:6em;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:white;
     background-color:purple;
     padding:0.2em 0.6em;
     border-right:1px solid white;
}
a:hover {background-color:#ff3300;}
li {display:inline;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
</ul>

<p>
      In the example above, we let the ul element and the a element float to the left.
      The li elements will be displayed as inline elements (no line break before or    after the element). This forces the list to be on one line.
      The ul element has a width of 100% and each hyperlink in the list has a width of 6em (6 times the size of the current font).
      We add some colors and borders to make it more fancy.
</p>
```

If in the style for ul, float is removed then the p text floats around ul. But my question is the float is applied to the link elements, not the ul. Then why is p so greedy about occupying the empty space of ul?

Please help clarify. Would appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph floats up next to the list menu because the UL no longer occupies 100% width since it's children links are floated.

Putting an `overflow:auto` rule on the UL or a `clear:left` on the paragraph will produce similar results where the paragraph doesn't float up next to the list.

This [W3C wiki entry](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing) might help understand:

> As you’ve seen above, the parent box doesn’t normally expand to
>   contain floated children. This can often cause confusion, for example
>   when all children of an element are floated when you make a horizontal
>   menu out of an unordered list by floating all the li elements. Since
>   floated boxes are taken out of the flow and don’t affect the parent
>   box, floating all the children effectively makes the parent empty and
>   it will collapse to zero height. Sometimes this is undesirable, for
>   instance if you want to set a background on the parent. If the parent
>   has zero height, no background will be visible.

Comment: Okay. Great. Isn't UL a block element? If so, then why is not p respecting ul's space?

Comment: Yes, a UL is a block level element, but since it's children are being floated, it essentially collapses and takes up no space, so the paragraph is actually sitting next to the list items `<li>`, not the list `<ul>`.